# Using a Lookup Relationship in a Formula Field

Tags: lookup, account, formula-field, contact, relationships

I want to update a field on the the account object based on a field being updated on the contact object, in this case a date / time field.

So far, I have setup a lookup relaionship field on the account object that is connected to the contact object. Then I created a formula field on the account object that calls the correlating field on the contact object via the lookup relationship. (Contact_to_Acc_Link__r.Form_Filled_Out_Date__c).

I went to test it by setting the date in that field on the contact, then checked the related account, but the field wasn't set.

What would cause it to fail? Or is there a better way of accomplishing this task?

Thank, Chase

Comment: Based on the scenario that you've outlined that the contact is the parent in this case and the account is the child, this formula field should work correctly and would be the best way to accomplish this. Check to make sure that the lookup is populated, as well as the field on contact.

Comment: If `Account` has a lookup to `Contact` through field `Contact_to_Acc_Link__c` then this will work provided the Account record has a value in field `Contact_to_Acc_Link__c`. However, your relationship name (based on the field name) seems backwards and unclear. What is it about this particular Contact that there is a lookup from Account to it?  For example, primary_contact__c or emergency_contact__c. And even then, this would be odd. Usually, I see this requirement when a value on one of the Account's Contacts needs to be shown at the Account level - and the solution requires triggers

Comment: Did you populate the field called `Contact to Acc Link`? If that field is empty, there is no Contact to draw information from.

Comment: @greenstork & @ Jeremy Nottingham, Thank you, I didn't realize the relationship field itself had to be populated. I added the contact I assosicated to the account in the lookup field and the data came right over.